# Setters/Getters at game programming?

Tags: oop

I was reading the sources for LibGDX, and I saw that there are too many public fields inside classes. So I was wondering, why? Is there any advantage instead setting up the typical setters/getters for that fields?

I know I should avoid direct accessing to class' fields, but if a guy like the author of LibGDX do it, I'm starting to doubt about "what are the best practices".

Comment: The advantage is, a getter/setter *can* allow a different implementation *without* changing the exposed interface. In some - perhaps most - cases of exposing public state this makes sense .. however, in the realm of game programming (and in particular games/graphic-engines with *highly-coupled structures* where *every microsecond counts*) the standard - and usually valid - arguments for getters/setters might not hold. But I don't do such game programming :) I would say, "use getters/setters" unless you *know* there is a reason not to, which involves performance tests on a particular target.

Comment: The best practice is to optimise if and when you find a bottleneck. LibGDX is meant for wide reuse, so if its data structures are used in tight inner loops, it might make sense to do the microoptimisation that is using fields instead of properties. (Field access is linearly faster than a getter call, inlining notwithstanding. And even then, it shouldn't be slower.) The author of such a library also can (and should) take the time to design his API carefully to not require it changing incompatibly in the future, so he's in a better position to make the call and trade flexibility for performance.

Comment: @pst Even in game programming, when *every microsecond counts*, turns out compiler optimizer are still better at making them count than humans are. You're still far better off using solid OOP practices and letting the compiler optimize it to bits (no pun intended, I'm so funny!). If your accessor methods aren't getting inlined, you've done something seriously wrong!

Comment: @corsiKa LibGDX is meant to be used for the Android Java implementation. The Java bytecode compiler doesn't really do much optimisations on its own, and the Dalvik VM didn't have JIT until Android. There's still probably only that much in optimisations it can do on mobile hardware, and it's possible the design is a legacy holdover from compatibility with 2.0 and 2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to know the implementation of this class, so they make your code simpler. Also, you are sure some variables you do not want them to be changed adheres to the rules. So they make sure you don't mess up with your code.

Comment: Really? Exactly how do getters make client code simpler? (There are valid reasons to use them, even pervasively, but that's not it.)

Comment: @millimoose Getters make client code simpler by consolidating any data acquisition logic. A simple (and bad) example would be if you wanted to return an empty string if your value was null. You put it in one place, not everywhere. You can't forget to do it. It makes it simpler by removing tens, hundreds, or thousands of duplicated lines.